# Obtaining value and setting new value using one function for different input fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Using vue, I have five input fields for different categories. I want to pass each input field into one function, manipulate the value, and then assign the updated value to the original input name.

Issue is, I cannot figure out how to take the value of an input field, perform a function, and assign the revised value to the object associated with the input field.

Edit: Updated code with current efforts

```
<template>
 <q-input
    v-model="categoryOne"
    name="categoryOne"
    @change="onSelected($event, categoryOne)"
 ></q-input>
 <q-input
    v-model="categoryTwo"
    name="categoryTwo"
    @change="onSelected($event, categoryTwo)"
></q-input>
</template>
</script>
export default {

setup() {
 let categoryOne = ref(null);
let categoryTwo = ref(null);

function onSelected(event, category) {
   //how would I take the input of each category and perform an 
   action that updates the original value? The only way I can figure 
   this out is to do it one-by-one, which seems sloppy and loses a 
  lot 
   of intended functionality.

   if (category === "categoryOne") { categoryOne.value = 
   categoryOne + 2 }
   if (category === "categoryTwo") { categoryTwo.value = 
   categoryTwo + 2 }
   
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: I think the reason your question hasn't had any responses is that its not clear what your challenge is. You have correctly wired up an event handler `onSelected` to the input's `@change` event ... so now you c an do whatever you want within that event handler. If you need help on HOW to do whatever it is you need to do, you'll have to post specific problem and what you've attempted to address it.

Comment: Understood. I've tried to update with what I know. I'm continuing to think it through

Comment: Please show the structure of categoryOne and categoryTwo - are these strings ... or objects with a .value property? It's not clear. On the one hand you use them with an input, (and since the attribute `type` is not specified, it should be a string. Then you pass category as your second argument to your onSelected function ... but then you don't use it - you refer to categoryOne and categoryTwo ... but these variables aren't declared.

Comment: The values of categoryOne and categoryTwo would be string inputs from the q-input text fields. I've updated to show the efforts to address your comments. While the above works for a manual process (that is, needing to address each category separately), I want the function to be able to apply to any object passed in, to update the value of the object. Thank you for your help to navigate this!

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand the question to be asking more about how cause two inputs to have side effects on one another, rather than the particulars of computing that side-effect.

The key is that UI controls can be bound bidirectionally to `data` via `v-model`. Below, input into one control side-effects the other.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    valueA: '',
    valueB: '',
  },
  methods: {
    changeA() {
      this.valueB = parseInt(this.valueA) + 2
    },
    changeB() {
      this.valueA = parseInt(this.valueB) + 2
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1></h1>
  <input type="text" v-model="valueA" @input="changeA()">
  <input type="text" v-model="valueB" @input="changeB">
</div>
```

Looking again after the question edit, maybe it is about the form of the side-effect, avoiding a list of conditionals. Lists of conditions are traditionally described by a series of `if` and optionally `elseif` blocks, with a switch.  With literal objects and closures, a more succinct option is available.

Here's the snippet using that idea...

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    valueA: '',
    valueB: '',
  },
  methods: {
    change(inputCategory) {
      // closures representing actions
      const actions = {
        one: () => this.valueB = +this.valueA + 2,
        two: () => this.valueA = +this.valueB + 2
      };
      // execute the closure with a given key
      actions[inputCategory]();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1></h1>
  <input type="text" v-model="valueA" @input="change('one')">
  <input type="text" v-model="valueB" @input="change('two')">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. The revised portion of your answer is giving me another direction. I'm new, and the right vocab is coming up short to clarify the question. Using your example, say I had ValueC, VD, and VE. I would like the method to take in whatever values were input by the user (some, all, or none), perform a function, and return the value to the original objects (ValueA-E). So if VA = 2 and VC = 4, the method would add two, and VA would equal 4, and VC would equal 6. I want to avoid listing out the Values individually in if statements.

Comment: @jdost_26 - do you mean you'd like to add 2 to several variables without mentioning them by name in the code?  Can we forget about input tags and vue and just work on that?

Comment: Sorry for delay. The handler flow was the answer I was looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70795699/firing-watcher-on-dynamic-fields/70796568#70796568. I realize I needed to wrap my head around the issue to ask the question better. Thank you for your time