# Firing watcher on dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a vue app using Quasar that loads a modal to perform a function once an image is selected. This works for a fixed value, but I cannot get it to work for a field that is created dynamically (meaning that the user can add them by clicking an "add field" button).

**Problems** I want to create one watcher that fires on each of the three fields (imgOne, imgTwo, and imgThree). I can get it to fire on the change of the array using the deep modifier, but that doesn't work for my purposes.

**Bonus Problem:** How to permit the file input field to be clearable without triggering watch.

```
  <q-file
    v-model="map"
    label="map"
  ></q-file>
  
 <div
    v-for="(field, i) in fields"
    :key="i"
  >
   <q-file
     v-model="fields[i].imgOne"
    ></q-file>
    <q-file
      v-model="fields[i].imgTwo"
    ></q-file>
    <q-file
      v-model="fields[i].imgThree"
    ></q-file>
  </div>

watch(map, (currentValue, oldValue) => {
  //this works to launch the modal
});

 watch(
  fields.imgOne,
  (currentValue, oldValue) => {
    //this does not work. I cannot use fields[i].imgOne or 
    //fields.value.imgOne
    //I want this to fire each time imgOne, imgTwo, or 
    //imgThree change
  },
  { deep: true }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintaining individual watcher for each entry in `fields` array (or 3 watchers if you want separate watcher for `imgOne`, `imgTwo` etc. - not clear from the question) is definitely possible but you need to fix few things:

1. Watcher must be added every time new field is added
2. You should probably store [return value](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#stopping-the-watcher) of `watch` to stop the watcher when the field is removed
3. As elements of the `fields` array are reactive objects and not `ref`s, the overload of `watch` receiving function must be used

```js
// after new field with index addedFieldIndex is added into array
// local variable
const addedFieldIndex = XX
const field = fields[addedFieldIndex]
field.watcher = watch(
  // watching multiple sources at once
  [
   () => field.imgOne,
   () => field.imgTwo,
   () => field.imgThree
  ], handler)
```

**Anyway** this is absolutely unnecessary and complicated. `watch` is not best tool in this situation imho. Much better tool is an `update:model-value` event (same event used by `v-model`) that is fired when the file is selected or cleared

```html
<q-file
  v-model="fields[i].imgThree"
  @update:model-value="onFileSelected(field, $event)"
></q-file>
```

```js
    const onFileSelected = (field, fileSelected) => {
      // null is used when field is cleared
      if(fileSelected !== null) {
        console.log("File ", fileSelected, " for field ", field.id)
      }
    }
```

Comment: In case you want to use a single event handler for all 3 fields and distinguish between them, just pass another argument into a handler like this: `@update:model-value="onFileSelected(field, $event, 'imgThree')"` ...it can really be anything you want, not just a string.

Comment: OFC handler declaration must also declare the argument like `const onFileSelected = (field, fileSelected, fieldName)` ..without it you will not be able to use it in the handler body

Comment: The handler strategy is exactly what I needed to close this off. Thank you! This has taken hours of wrong directions.