# Getting v-model from a quasar file picker field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

In a vue app using quasar, I have three file picker fields, and when one of those fields change, I want to call a specific function. I want to be able to pass the v-model as a variable into the function so I can update the v-model using the function.

See more problem description in the onSelected function description.

For example, I may want to bind the v-model of whatever field was changed to a new variable. So how would I tell the function what v-model was passed at the @change event?

```
<q-file
      v-model="fieldOne"
      @change="onSelected()"
></q-file>
<q-file
      v-model="fieldTwo"
      @change="onSelected()"
></q-file>
<q-file
      v-model="fieldThree"
      @change="onSelected()"
></q-file>

 function onSelected(event) {
  // I would like to update the v-model of the field that was 
  // subject to the @change event. event.target.value doesn't 
  // work. How to I work with the specific v-model that 
  // triggered 
  //the @change event?
  
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70796568/381282

Comment: I really appreciate this! using the link above, I've restructured code, but I get the file selected and event. How would onSelected tell which v-model was passed to it? Is that in the event somewhere?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think i am entitled to anything. I was going to get you to post this as the answer when you were done. My apologies and I appreciate your time in helping me out with your previous posts. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry. Just a bit frustrated by some people here. Check my linked answer...\

Comment: I understand -- ive seen that here too. I'm new and certainly don't want to be in that crowd, so I'm sorry for my lack of responsiveness. You're welcome to post the handler response as an answer here as that answers this question.